# Password for Socks Proxy with SSH Tunnel

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, proxy, tunnel

I need to have a socks5 proxy with an ssh tunnel with the following command:

`ssh -p <SSH_PORT> -CnfND 0.0.0.0:<Port> Username@ServerIP`

The question is how can I set a password for this connection?

as you can see everyone can connect to the server which the above command invoked in it with knowing oppened `Port` because of the `0.0.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

To secure the connection with a password, you can use public key authentication instead of a password. In this approach, you generate a public/private key pair on your local machine, copy the public key to the server, and then use the private key to authenticate the connection.

Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. Generate a public/private key pair on your local machine:

```bash
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

2. Copy the public key to the server:

```bash
ssh-copy-id -p <SSH_PORT> -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub UserName@ServerIP
```

3. Connect to the server using the private key:

```bash
ssh -p <SSH_PORT> -CnfND 0.0.0.0:<Port> -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa UserName@ServerIP
```

With this setup, you'll be prompted to enter your private key passphrase (if one was set) instead of a password, and the connection will only be established if the public key on the server matches the private key on your local machine.

Note: Make sure to keep the private key secure and protected, as anyone with access to the private key can use it to connect to the server.

Comment: After this connection is established, any user will be able to use the proxy. Am I wrong? IMO the question is about restricting access *to the proxy*. Maybe the OP should be more clear.